Android：Using ViewPager + Fragment method, how to solve off-screen Fragment participation RenderThread drawing？
Android Using the ViewPager + Fragment method, if Fragment1 has been opened and then cut to Fragment2, then Fragment1 is cached off-screen, it is not visible on the screen, but RenderThread will still draw Fragment1. From a performance perspective, how can RenderThread not draw Fragment1?
I hope to solve this problem in order to achieve the purpose of optimizing performance

use
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1)

